# Devstack Juno: ImportError: No module named persistence.backends.sql

Tags: openstack, devstack, keystone, openstack-juno

Deploying openstack using devstack ran across this error when I use keystone commands.

[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/var/www/keystone/main", line 51, in 
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     drivers = service.load_backends()
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/service.py", line 58, in load_backends
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     token_api=token.Manager(),
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/dependency.py", line 166, in wrapper
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     self.**wrapped_init**(*args, **kwargs)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/dependency.py", line 106, in **wrapped_init**
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     init(self, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/token/core.py", line 113, in **init**
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     super(Manager, self).**init**(CONF.token.driver)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/manager.py", line 70, in **init**
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     self.driver = importutils.import_object(driver_name)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 38, in import_object
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 28, in import_class
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15]     **import**(mod_str)
[Thu Nov 27 09:20:59 2014] [error] [client 172.20.14.15] ImportError: No module named persistence.backends.sql

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

> driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token

in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf